# Top Layout Guide deprecated since iOS 11 - unable to find view

Tags: swift, autolayout, ios11

I am getting the following errors:

[image]

But i am unable to find the view which occurs that warnings. When ill delete all views in the Storyboard, and perform a "Clean" - the warnings are still present.

Any ideas how to find that view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any ideas how to find that view?

It's not a "view"; it's the storyboard itself. Edit the storyboard and check Use Safe Area Layout Guides:

[image]

Also you might need to quit Xcode and clean out the DerivedData folder so as to get a completely clean build.

Comment: Thanks - ive already used that checkbox before (but nothing changes after cleaning) - but now WITH CLOSING xCode AND cleaning again, the warnings disappear.

Answer (score -1):

```
let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

//put the code like this
view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: This does not appear to address the question posed by OP.