# Storyboard and "Bottom layout guide is deprecated since iOS 11.0" warning

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard, ios11, safearealayoutguide

I'm getting this warning when building:

> /* com.apple.ibtool.document.warnings */
>   /[path]/MyStoryboard.storyboard:xxx-xx-xxx: warning: Bottom layout
>   guide is deprecated since iOS 11.0 [7]

I've read some posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432239/top-layout-guide-deprecated-since-ios-11-unable-to-find-view). I have the `Use Safe Area Layout Guides` of the `storyboard` file already selected, and cleaning the build folder did not work either, I keep getting such warning. What else could I be missing?

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure this is unchecked, then run it on a simulator and that will fix your error.

[image: screenshot]